# Wordpress, JQuery.post to ajaxurl, empty response

Tags: wordpress

Folks, please help to resolve some issue with Wordpress (latest version). 
On some servers (rare servers), jQuery.post fails in the theme.

To save theme settings the following JS code is executed:

```
                jQuery.post(
                    ajaxurl,
                    {
                        action : 'options_save',
                        nonce : form.attr('data-nonce'),
                        data : form.find('input').serialize()
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        confirm(response);
                    }
                );
```

Problem is that if data parameter (form.find('input').serialize()) is more ~550 bytes in length, the request fails with error 404 (admin-ajx.php is not found). If size of serialized data is less 550 bytes, then request processes well.

Saying more, error 404 can be solved if I set permalink structure in Wordpress as Default. Why permalink structure affects admin part at all? But the request fails anyway. I tried to track why it fails, I added the code print_r($_REQUEST) to admin-ajax.php, and found that if the data is more ~550 bytes, the $_REQUEST is empty array, if data less 550 bytes, the $_REQUEST contains correct data that I sent in jQuery.post.

What hell is going on?

Note, this happens only on 1 of 50 servers, latest Wordpress version is used and no plugins are used at all.

Comment: Could you verify if what your max_post_size is? `echo ini_get('max_post_size');`

Comment: max_post_size is 48M, all php variables are OK as I checked. The most strange thing, if I copy file admin-ajax.php to admin-ajax1.php and redirect my jQuery.post from ajaxurl to 'admin-ajax1.php', then everything becomes to work well. What is the magic with this particular file name? Also, even if I put empty php script instead of admin-ajax.php, then it is never executed if data size > 550 bytes.